# What is the origin of current or charge carriers in an semiconductor and how many charge carriers can exist in Silicon at zero Kelvin?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics

What is the origin of current or charge carriers in an intrinsic semiconductor?

There is some conductivity in a intrinsic semiconductor and when you look at the electronic distribution of Si atoms in a semiconductor, you will find that all the electrons in a Si atoms are bonded with each other. Now the question arises that how does the bond is breaking occurs in order to start the conductivity?

Answer (score 1):

At 0K, all valence electrons are indeed bonded in covalent bonds and thus are localized. The semiconductor behaves like an insulator (in the absence of crystallographic defects).

At temperatures above 0K, the electrons can break away from their bonds due to the thermal energy supplied to them. They then can move around the lattice. If a voltage is applied, they thus can contribute to conduct current.

Answer (score 0):

**Reminder:** *semiconductors* are just *insulators* with a narrow bandgap (that is the bandgap typiclaly comparable to the room temperature).

Thus, in an intrinsic semiconductor at zero temperature all the electrons are in the valence band and none of them is excited above the gap to the conduction band, thus an intrinsic semiconductor at zero temperature has no free charge careers.

Interpreting excited electrons in terms of bonds is a bit awkward way to look at generation of carriers by temperature, since electrons in the conduction band are excitations of a crystal as a whole rather than a result of breaking a specific bond. Nevertheless, one can look at it from this angle as well: breaking a bond requires energy, which means that at zero temperature no bonds a broken.

Note that even a doped semiconductor at zero temperature is non-conducting, although the energy required to make it conducting is much smaller, due to the proximity of the impurity levels to the bands.

Finally, by *intrinsic semiconductor* we usually mean a crystal with no defects. If the crystal has defects that will act pretty much like doping, i.e., lesser temperatures may be required to excited current carriers.